# With Google drive api - java sdk - how to get file revisions filtered by date

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I'd like to get via the Google Drive API java SDK the list of revisions that happened after a date.

I tried to use the class [Drive.Revisions.list](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/Drive.Revisions.List.html) but I cannot see how to filter revisions by date.

The only way I could get the list of revisions that happened after a date is by exploring all the revisions in the client side. I would like to find a way to let the filtering happen at the level of the API.

Comment: Which Google Drive API? Javascript? Modify your question and it might be reopened.

Comment: @xtratic I clarified the question

Comment: I assume you've read the API, which methods have you tried? Being able to learn an API is an important skill, sometimes just experimenting can help you figure things out. If you add something you've tried then that should probably be enough to reopen this question.

Comment: I updated the question @xtratic. Can you reopen it?

Comment: I have nominated your question for reopening